# Remove duplicate header lines in dataframe

Tags: r

My raw data contains numeric values with a recall of the headers every 20 lines.

I wish to remove the repeated header lines with R. I know it's quite easy with `sed` command but I wish the R script to handle all steps of tidying data.

```
> raw <- read.delim("./vmstat_archiveadm_s.txt")
> head(raw)
kthr      memory            page            disk          faults      cpu
r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr s2 s3 vc --   in   sy   cs us sy id
0 0 0 100097600 97779056 285 426 53 0 0 0 367 86 6 0 0 1206 7711 2630 1  0 99
0 0 0 96908192 94414488 7 31 0 0  0  0  0 120 0  0  0 2782 5775 5042  2  0 97
0 0 0 96889840 94397152 0 1 0  0  0  0  0 122 0  0  0 2737 5591 4958  2  0 97
kthr      memory            page            disk          faults      cpu
r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr s2 s3 vc --   in   sy   cs us sy id
0 0 0 100065744 97745448 282 422 52 0 0 0 363 89 6 0 0 1233 7690 2665 1  0 99
0 0 0 96725312 94222040 7 31 0 0  0  0  0 604 69 0  0 5269 5703 7910  2  1 97
0 0 0 96668624 94170784 0 0 0  0  0  0  0 155 53 0  0 3047 5505 5317  2  0 97
0 0 0 96595104 94086816 0 0 0  0  0  0  0 174 0  0  0 2879 5567 5068  2  0 97
1 0 0 96521376 94025504 0 0 0  0  0  0  0 121 0  0  0 2812 5471 5105  2  0 97
0 0 0 96503256 93994896 0 0 0  0  0  0  0 121 0  0  0 2731 5621 4981  2  0 97
(...)
```

Comment: Do you know it's always every 20 lines? exactly every 20?

Comment: Lines 1, 6, 27, 48, 69, 90, ...

Comment: Call `sed` from inside R using `system()` or something similar? No point complicating things if you already have a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :
where `df` is the dataframe

```
x = seq(6,100,21)
df = df[-x,]
```

Sequence will generate a string of numbers from 6 till 100 at an interval of 21.

Therefore, in this case :

```
  6 27 48 69 90
```

Remove them from the dataframe by

```
 df[-x,]
```

**EDIT:**

To do this for the entire dataframe, replace 100 with number of rows. i.e

```
seq(6,nrow(df),21)
```

Comment: This is not enought as there are two lines of headers and other dummy lines. I cannot just rely on a build sequence. Thanks however. I'd like to avoid preprocessing the raw data before R processing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of processing the output in R I will clean it at the generation level:

```
$ vmstat 1 | egrep -v '^ kthr|^ r'
0 0 0 154831904 153906536 215 471 0 0 0 0 526 33 32 0 0 1834 14171 5253 0 0 99
1 0 0 154805632 153354296 9 32 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0 1463  610  739  0  0 100
1 0 0 154805632 153354696 0 4 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 1408  425  634  0  0 100
0 0 0 154805632 153354696 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 1341  381  658  0  0 100
0 0 0 154805632 153354696 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 1299  353  610  0  0 100
1 0 0 154805632 153354696 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 1319  375  638  0  0 100
0 0 0 154805632 153354640 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 1308  367  614  0  0 100
0 0 0 154805632 153354640 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 1336  395  650  0  0 100
1 0 0 154805632 153354640 0 0 0 0 0  0  0 44 44  0  0 1594  378  878  0  0 100
0 0 0 154805632 153354640 0 0 0 0 0  0  0 66 65  0  0 1763  382 1015  0  0 100
0 0 0 154805632 153354640 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 1312  411  645  0  0 100
0 0 0 154805632 153354640 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 1342  390  647  0  0 100
```